# Seeking Resources for Implementing Self-Consistent Numerical Calculation of Retarded Green's Function

Tags: resource-recommendations, computational-physics, simulations, greens-functions

I'm seeking resources or references to learn how to implement a self-consistent numerical calculation for the retarded Green's function $G^R(\vec{p},E)$, which is defined as:
$$
G^R(\vec{p},E) = \frac{1}{E-H_0(\vec{p}) - \Sigma^R(\vec{p},E)}.
$$
In this equation, $H_0(\vec{p})$ represents the non-interacting part of the Hamiltonian. When dealing with a delta function impurity potential, the self-energy $\Sigma^R(E)$ is computed using the T-matrix approximation. This results in the expression:
$$
\Sigma^R(E) = n_{i}T(E) = \frac{n_{i} u}{1-\sum_{\vec{q}} G^R(\vec{q},E) u} 
$$
Here, $n_i$ represents the impurity concentration and $u$ is the strength of the impurity.

I'm interested in finding materials, such as books or articles, that provide guidance on how to develop a self-consistent iterative loop to numerically compute $G^R(\vec{p},E)$ for a given $H_0(\vec{p})$, preferably in a programming language. Your suggestions would be greatly appreciated.